# Validar input de email usando Jquery.MaskedInput e/ou Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, preciso validar um input de e-mail. Inseri no HTML o JQuery e um plugin que achei, o Jquery.maskedInput. Consegui fazer máscaras para telefone, cep, cpf, mas para e-mail não sei como proceder. Abaixo está um input que fiz de CPF e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></script><!--Necessário para as mascaras dos inputs-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script><!--Necessário para as mascaras dos inputs-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
    });
  </script>

<p><input id="cpf"class="notNull" placeholder="CPF" oninput="this.className = ''" name="mil_cpf"></p>
</html>
```

Preciso fazer a manipulação do input pelo ID dele, pois a classe já estou usando pra outra coisa. Agradeço desde já quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim

```
$('#email').mask("A", {
    translation: {
        "A": { pattern: /[\w@\-.+]/, recursive: true }
    }
});
```

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780184/jquery-mask-plugin-to-mask-email-addresses-and-web-urls

Comment: Coloquei desse jeito,não foi, dei uma olhada no link que está como fonte, também não tive sucesso